# Why rationals for limits at infinity?

Tags: calculus

In James Stewart's Calculus (8th edition) the theorem is given

> If $r > 0$ is a rational number, then
> $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^r} = 0$

But why specify that the power $r$ must be rational instead of a real number so that the irrationals are included as well?

I have found that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^r} = 0$  still even when setting $r$ to be an irrational such as $r = \pi, e, \sqrt{2}$.

Is there an irrational number where this isn't the case and hence why they are excluded from the theorem?

Comment: How is rational used in the proof?

Comment: As a guess:  at that point in the text perhaps they have not yet defined $x^r$ for irrational $r$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Unfortunately, no proof is provided.

Comment: @lulu Hmmm I see.